# how to solve following error in python

Tags: python, numpy

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
import numpy

im1 = Image.open("C:\Users...l8\B2.TIF")
im2 = Image.open("C:\Users\...l8\B3.TIF")
im3 = Image.open("C:\Users\.....\l8\B4.TIF")
im4 = Image.open("C:\Users\.........\l8\B8.TIF")
im1 = im1.resize((im4.size[0], im4.size[1]), Image.ANTIALIAS)
im2 = im2.resize((im4.size[0], im4.size[1]), Image.ANTIALIAS)
im3 = im3.resize((im4.size[0], im4.size[1]), Image.ANTIALIAS)
arr1 = np.array(im1)
arr2 = np.array(im2)
arr3 = np.array(im3)
arr4 = np.array(im4)

V1=(arr1+arr2-2*arr3)
V2=(arr1-arr2)
y= sqrt(2)
 x= sqrt(6)
 x1 = [[None for col in range(V1.shape[0])] for row in   range(V1.shape[1])]
y1 = [[None for col in range(V1.shape[0])] for row in range(V1.shape[1])]




for i in range(V1.shape[0]):
      for j in range(V1.shape[1]):
          x1[i][j] = (V1[i][j])/x
          y1[i][j] = (V2[i][j])/y
```

i got following error
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\shaheera\Desktop\ihs.py", line 35, in 
         x1[i][j] = (V1[i][j])/x
     IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the error is (indentation seems likely), but you *really* don't need to go back to list comprehension when you already have a numpy array.

Just do

```
V1=(arr1+arr2-2*arr3)
V2=(arr1-arr2)
x1=V1/np.sqrt(6)
y1=V2/np.sqrt(2)
```

Comment: @Danial with ur solution i tried and got the error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\ihs.py", line 20, in <module>
    x1 = V1/np.sqrt(6)
MemoryError

Comment: input file size is 100MB

Comment: You're likely holding too many things in memory and running out of RAM.  Try just going straight to `x1=(arr1+arr2-2*arr3)/np.sqrt(6)` without calculating V1.  Or close some other programs.

Comment: again memory error...when i do x1=(arr1+arr2-2*arr3) then it runs fine. bt as soon as i divide it by np.sqrt(6), it gives memory error

Comment: set `x=1/sqrt(6)` and multiply instead.  Did your original code work after the indent error was fixed?  Are the elements of the original array integers?

Comment: Better yet, comment everything after `arr1 = np.array(im1)` and `print(arr1.dtype)` and tell me what it spits out

Answer (score 0):

As for your list comprehension, you've got your list indices backwards.  Switch i and j in the last two lines.

`x1[i][j]` is **(x1[i])**[j], but i is length `V1.shape[0]` and the outer list is length `V1.shape[1]`.

But you're probably still going to have memory errors.